# Is there a work around for "URI malformed" error after Google Android Security update 2017-07-01

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

MobileFirst 7.1 hybrid app on Android devices with [Google Security patch 2017-07-01](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2017-07-01) are throwing a "URIError: URI malformed" error at line 123 of worklight.js

The hybrid app works fine on iOS devices and Android devices without the 2017-07-01 security patch.

Is anyone else encountering issues with MobileFirst hybrid apps on Android after this patch is installed?

Is there a work-around for this or an IBM fix?

Comment: What version & device of Android is this on ?

Comment: This a Pixel XL, Android version 7.1.2, kernel 3.18.etc , build NHG470 Security patch level July 5, 2017

Answer (score 1):

We were able to work around this by forcing the responses from adapter calls to be UTF-8 like this;

```
function adapterProcedure(input) {

    var rtn = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    rtn = JSON.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(rtn))));
    return rtn;
}
```